# Why font-awesome works on localhost but not on web ?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, font-awesome

I'm using font awesome in my project`(mvc/asp.net)`. My problem is, I was debugging the project and check on `localhost`, there was no problem with font awesome icons. But when published the website and check on web, instead of icons, i saw small boxes. I'm sure that it's placed in right directory(where `css` files placed).

I couldn't find any proper solution.

By the way there is also no problem with buttons. They are all ok but icons are gone.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the link to the site? Or Check source path. Have you copied icons to the publish folder?

Comment: Are you using icons locally and if so have you copied them to publish folder? which icons are missing on the given link. I can't see any missing boxes.

Comment: On the footer part, near the social media and other infos, I used font awesome icons. As far as I know, it is not needed to include icon files with font awesome.It generates the icons itself.  ex:<i class="icon-facebook-sign icon-1x"></i> generates the facebook icon etc..

Comment: You could see this thread about fonts not rendering properly. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32692151/fonts-are-not-rendered-correctly-in-release-mode-but-is-working-on-debug-mode-i?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I've just loaded your webpage and checked the net tab of firebug.

your following urls returned a 404:

http://www.senocakonline.com/Content/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff

http://www.senocakonline.com/Content/font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf

i would assume that those being missing is the reason your icons aren't displaying.

UPDATE: 23.10.2015
to make it available just add this code to your WebConfig:

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension="woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension="woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: i had the same issue to access font awesome fonts, for **other solutions**  try these links which deals with `StyleBundle` **virtualpath**: [Link 1](http://www.mvccentral.net/story/details/articles/kahanu/stylebundle-403-error-solved) , [Link 2](http://forums.asp.net/t/1774324.aspx?MVC4+css+bundling+and+image+references), [Link 3](http://ericpanorel.net/2013/10/25/font-awesome-4-0-mvc-bundling-and-minification/), [Link 4](http://jameschambers.com/2014/08/adding-some-font-awesome-to-mvc-and-bootstrap/) , hope this helps someone.

Comment: Wow - I _totally_ didn't know about this. After raging about these WOFF files causing 404s - your answer nailed it. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I was able to find this right away and not spent hours - as with too many other things asp.net to mention.

Answer (score 34):

**Why font-awesome works on debug mode but not on IIS?**

In Visual Studio, by default, some font files are not including during Publish:

- .eot
- .json
- .ttf
- .woff

This is because their **build action** is set to **None**, this is by default (on MVC, not sure on WebForms). You must go to the affected file's properties and set it from "None" to "Content".

[image]

This is how I solved it (not by manually dragging the files as some may suggest)

Credits goes to this guy: http://edsykes.blogspot.com/2012/09/aspnet-build-actions-with-ttf-eot-and.html

Comment: glad to be of help :)

Comment: those files are set to Content by default but glad it helped other people. It is also not font-awesome specific but rather to the files extensions

Comment: I tried everything else and was happily surprised that this was the correct answer.  Thanks, never even crossed my mind that this was an issue to be aware off.  Again thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Another solution that solved this issue for me can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12587256/615285

Quoting from there:

The issue is most likely that the icons/images in the css files are using relative paths, so if your bundle doesn't live in the same app relative path as your unbundled css files, they become broken links.

The easist thing to do is to have your bundle path look like the css directory so the relative urls just work, i.e:

```
new StyleBundle("~/Static/Css/bootstrap/bundle")
```

We have added support for this in the 1.1beta1 release, so to automatically rewrite the image urls, you can add a new ItemTransform which does this rebasing automatically.

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/publiccss").Include(
            "~/Static/Css/bootstrap/bootstrap.css",
            "~/Static/Css/bootstrap/bootstrap-padding-top.css",
            "~/Static/Css/bootstrap/bootstrap-responsive.css",
            "~/Static/Css/bootstrap/docs.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform()));
```

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem. The solution:

1. Open CSS file and delete the current font-face section and replace with these:

   ```
   @font-face {

       font-family: FontAwesome;
       src: url('/Content/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot'), /*for IE */
            url('/Content/fonts/fontawesomewebfont.svg'),
            url('/Content/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf'); /* for CSS3 browsers */
       font-weight: normal;
       font-style: normal;
   }
   ```

   (change the font-face values as you want)
2. **Copy your ttf font file on your desktop** then convert to eot

   > > > http://www.kirsle.net/wizards/ttf2eot.cgi
3. Convert ttf font file to svg

   > > > http://www.freefontconverter.com/
4. Convert ttf font file to woff (optional)

   > > > http://ttf2woff.com/
5. Drag and drop these all fonts (ttf, eot, svg, woff... ) to your file location when Visual Studio 2012 is open.
6. Publish your project

Comment: Yes, it is all to do with putting the files in the right folder.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on this code line in `BundleConfig`:

```
        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

if it is true, you have to change your Font files's path;

`../` is shows `root path, main folder of your project`. And then you have to write rest of the path.

Mine. When it's true:

```
font-family: 'Icons';
    src:url('../_include/css/fonts/Icons.eot');
    src:url('../_include/css/fonts/Icons.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../_include/css/fonts/Icons.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../_include/css/fonts/Icons.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('../_include/css/fonts/Icons.svg#Icons') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
```

When it's false:

```
font-family: 'Icons';
    src:url('fonts/Icons.eot');
    src:url('fonts/Icons.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/Icons.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/Icons.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('fonts/Icons.svg#Icons') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is also a MIME TYPE problem in the IIS, just add the file extension .woff and it will work

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me :
<
link href="~/Content/font-awesome-4.2.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />

I had to link the Directly URl

Comment: thanks for answering. If you comment is part of the answer, you can edit the answer and put it in there. BTW, what is a "Directly URI"? (I know what a URI is, I just have never seen).

Answer (score 0):

In my ASP.NET MVC project with bundling enabled in BundleConfig.cs what worked was this:

Open the file `font-awesome.css` and change `@font-face` to this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=3.2.1');
  src: url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=3.2.1') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.2.1') format('woff'), url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=3.2.1') format('truetype'), url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.svg#fontawesomeregular?v=3.2.1') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

I had to add `../` before each `url`.

Comment: An anonymous user [suggests](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5269701) to do a style override in another file, like custom.css, instead of editing the original font-awesome.css source.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Fonts were shown on local properly but when I uploded it to server, only blank squares were shown.
Sometimes it may happen because the filename mentioned in FontAwesome CSS file src attribute is different from the actual font file name. In my case I found it like this in fontawesome css file:

```
    @font-face {
            font-family: 'FontAwesome';
            src: url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=3.2.1');
            src: url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=3.2.1') format('embedded-opentype'),
                url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.2.1') format('woff'),
                url('../font/fontawesome-webfont_aea8981c.ttf?v=3.2.1') format('truetype'),
                url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.svg#fontawesomeregular?v=3.2.1') format('svg');
            font-weight: normal;
            font-style: normal;
        }
```

But the actual font file names wese like these-

```
        font/fontawesome-webfont_2d2816fe.eot
        font/fontawesome-webfont_aea8981c.eot
        font/fontawesome-webfont_aea8981c.ttf
        font/fontawesome-webfont_aea8981c.woff
```

though the name didn't match properly in css file after underscore, it was working fine on local. So it was hard to tell what was the probable cause for that.
 When I edited the name of file in FontAwesome css file src to the exact actual names, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing realy worked for me.
I have a Webform page that hosts an angulular application.
The angular application uses the webfonts.

The trick with CssRewriteUrlTransform() was the right direction, but then I found this extension for bundleing that did the final solution!

[AspNetBundling](https://github.com/benmccallum/AspNetBundling/blob/bf846324791780443f88d64c9899aef47b8d338e/AspNetBundling/CssRewriteUrlTransformFixed.cs#L12)

You don't have to use the hole extension, just copy the CssRewriteUrlTransformFixed class and use it instead of the original.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all suggestions above, and none of them work. Then I tried to move font CSS file to different CSS file, and magic has happen. Everything start to work without any problems. Note you can later on bundle new CSS file through your bundle file.