# Font not displaying properly when website uploaded to live hosting

Tags: html

I am trying to create a simple html landing page using bootstrap.

When I open it using google chrome locally, everything is displaying fine.

However, when I upload the page to my hosting, the font suddenly starts displaying weird symbols for my language (see picture).

[image]

Do you know where the problem could be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why font-awesome works on localhost but not on web ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14894935/why-font-awesome-works-on-localhost-but-not-on-web)

Comment: How does the page define its character encoding? My guess is it doesn't, so it leaves the browsers to guess.

Comment: Yeah, that looks like a character encoding mismatch, not a font issue.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Thanks guys!