# Font-Awesome Get Request Failure When Bundling EnableOptimizations is true

Tags: asp.net-mvc, font-awesome, bundling-and-minification

I am experiencing a problem with font-awesome and ASP.NET’s optimisation/bundling feature.

When EnableOptimizations is set to false, the font which I'm using for a loading image works perfectly:
[image]

However, when EnableOptimizations is set to true, the font is no longer found and the following is displayed:[image]

I’ve noticed there is a disparity between the paths which the GET requests are hitting:

EnableOptimizations = false: **localhost:3620/Content/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.1.0**
EnableOptimizations = true: **localhost:3620/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.1.0**

The bundle in question looks like this:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/BootstrapAndFontAwesome").Include(
    "~/Content/bootstrap/bootstrapLabel.css",
    "~/Content/font-awesome/font-awesome.css"
    ));
```

What’s going on here and what’s the best way to fix it?

Cheers

**Update**

On Rowan's suggestion in the comments to this post, I implemented the following code from this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17702773/540156) which has fixed the problem on my dev machine:

```
public class CssRewriteUrlTransformWrapper : IItemTransform
{
    public string Process(string includedVirtualPath, string input)
    {
        return new CssRewriteUrlTransform().Process("~" + VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(includedVirtualPath), input);
    }
}
```

I will need to do a few practice deployments to make sure it is solid (e.g. use virtual IIS directories etc.). Looks good so far!

Note that I did have to separate out the font-awesome file into it's own bundle as it cannot be bundled with another resource when adopting the CssRewriteUrlTransform solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a minified version as well (`font-awesome.min.css`)?

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes. There is a minified version. I believe the font-awesome css is using a relative path and that is where the issue is. Makes me wonder why this is not a common thing as I installed it using Nuget.

Comment: It may well be a problem with the minified file. Try deleting it and let the bundler do the minification of the standard file.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I just tried your suggestion, and alas, it has not rectified the issue.

Comment: Does using [`CssRewriteUrlTransform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.optimization.cssrewriteurltransform(v=vs.110).aspx) help? I somehow recall it being a possible solution? Eg `bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/mycss").Include("~/Content/font-awesome.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform()));`

Comment: @RowanFreeman That pretty much worked, I used a wrapper for it which I will put in the original post as an edit/update. Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither this or Rowan's anwsers didn't help me after publishing - it is still not working. Only disabling optimization works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`CssRewriteUrlTransform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.optimization.cssrewriteurltransform(v=vs.110).aspx).

> Rewrites urls to be absolute so assets will still be found after bundling.

Example:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/mycss")
    .Include("~/Content/font-awesome.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform()));
```

Answer (score 2):

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12587256/429973) has a useful solution to this issue, and it appears to have been written by someone who actually works for Microsoft on the ASP.net Bundle code.

> The issue is most likely that the icons/images in the css files are
>   using relative paths, so if your bundle doesn't live in the same app
>   relative path as your unbundled css files, they become broken links.
>
> We have rebasing urls in css on our todo list, but for now, the easist
>   thing to do is to have your bundle path look like the css directory so
>   the relative urls just work, i.e:

```
new StyleBundle("~/Static/Css/bootstrap/bundle")
```

> Update: We have added support for this in the 1.1beta1 release, so to
>   automatically rewrite the image urls, you can add a new ItemTransform
>   which does this rebasing automatically.

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/publiccss").Include(
            "~/Static/Css/bootstrap/bootstrap.css",
            "~/Static/Css/bootstrap/bootstrap-padding-top.css",
            "~/Static/Css/bootstrap/bootstrap-responsive.css",
            "~/Static/Css/bootstrap/docs.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform()));
```

---

This fixed my issue with getting 404 errors on Font Awesome icons, on the production server, due to the relative paths not being used correctly.

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/font-awesome/css/bundle").Include(
      "~/Content/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform()));
```

Answer (score 0):

There’s a little know class called CssRewriteUrlTransform in the Sytem.Web.Optimization namespace that will help us solve this issue, or any css file that references url relative resources. The new code would now look something like:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/content/smartadmin")
            .Include("~/content/css/font-awesome.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())
            .Include("~/content/css/dataTables.responsive.css")
            .IncludeDirectory("~/content/css", "*.min.css"));
```