# mvc bundling and relative css image when website is deployed to an application

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, bundle, bundling-and-minification

To convert relative image paths to absolute path there are many questions asked and answered in stackoverflow like this one:

[MVC4 StyleBundle not resolving images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355935/mvc4-stylebundle-not-resolving-images)

that suggest adding `new CssRewriteUrlTransform()` as below:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css/jquery-ui/bundle")
       .Include("~/Content/css/jquery-ui/*.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform()));
```

and this actually have saved me before. but now that I deploy my website to an application (not root of a website) there is still a problem:

the application is:

```
http://localhost/sample/
```

but the image urls are like:

```
http://localhost/css/imgs/spirit.png
```

while it should be:

```
 http://localhost/sample/css/imgs/spirit.png
```

although the bundled css link itself is correct and working.

Comment: Is sample a virtual directory on IIS?

Comment: it is an application and virtual directory in IIS. in this sample the application name is **sample**

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765238/cssrewriteurltransform-with-or-without-virtual-directory which completely describes *what happened* and *what you need to do*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If there are no virtual directories involved the following code would do:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/css").Include(
                "~/Content/css/*.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform()));
```

but when VirtualDirectory is used CssRewriteUrlTransform will rewrite to Host instead of Host/VirtualDirectory. the solution is to derive CssRewriteUrlTransform which is fully discussed here: [ASP.NET MVC4 Bundling with Twitter Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12577108/asp-net-mvc4-bundling-with-twitter-bootstrap?rq=1):

```
public class CssRewriteUrlTransformWrapper : IItemTransform
{
    public string Process(string includedVirtualPath, string input)
    {           
        return new CssRewriteUrlTransform().Process("~" + VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(includedVirtualPath), input);           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> This is actually just another issue with optimizations in general not
>   working correctly when the app is running as a virtual directory.

Since you're using a virtual directory for hosting your website, So you should make a wrapper that will call `CssRewriteUrlTransform` with the fixed path:

```
public class CssRewriteUrlTransformWrapper : IItemTransform
{
        public string Process(string includedVirtualPath, string input)
        {           
            return new CssRewriteUrlTransform().Process("~" + VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(includedVirtualPath), input);           
        }
}
```

[More info](http://aspnetoptimization.codeplex.com/workitem/83).