# How to deal with relative image URL changing when CSS is minified?

Tags: css, web, minify

## The Problem

I have a large website, so my CSS folder structure can be rather deep. Any CSS file can set an element's background image via a [relative URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940451/using-relative-url-in-css-file-what-location-is-it-relative-to). Before releasing to my production servers, I need to minify all CSS files. This minification process may break some of the relative URLs because it effectively flattens the folder structure. As a developer, how do you deal with this discrepancy between development and production code?

## Example

This is my folder structure:

```
image/
    article/
        brushStroke.jpg
style/
    module/
        button.css
    page/
        article/
            introToPainting.css
    minified/
        style20130522.css
```

During development, I may have this CSS rule in *introToPainting.css*:

```
#step1 {
    background-image: url(../../../image/article/brushStroke.jpg);
}
```

Let's say on a particular simple page, I only need *button.css* and *introToPainting.css*. For production release, these two CSS files will be minified into style20130522.css. Now that the minified file resides in a different folder depth than *introToPainting.css*, the path to *brushStroke.jpg* is now wrong.

http://scs.veetle.com/soget/session-thumbnails/5363e222d2e10/0eaf8f26f193375f97b7deeabae97016/5363e222d2e10_0eaf8f26f193375f97b7deeabae97016_20140509184555_536d84d367530_74_896x672.jpg

[http://scs.veetle.com/soget/session-thumbnails/534711b951df7/60d40fd7ca34cf794237c5ec8cb4ff6d/534711b951df7_60d40fd7ca34cf794237c5ec8cb4ff6d_20140521112148_537ceebcd74e0_98_896x672.jpg](http://beta.vidopop.com/v/1iexo6t)

Comment: yeah ... store the CSS files u develop on in the same relative folder as the one that would be referenced in production. or use absolute referencing. u cant have relative reference, change the relative positioning, and expect it to magically work.

Comment: Yeah that seems like the logical choice unless you change all your file paths prior to launch, even is you have folder/folder/css and you put minified in folder/folder/min/ the relative paths would be the same

Comment: I can't use an absolute path. I work in a team. Each developer's environment may have a different base URL.

Comment: There is a library that will allow you to preprocess your CSS before it's served so you can change all the paths https://nuget.org/packages/RxLoader/

Comment: All CSS preprocessors should update the relative URLs.  The fact that they alter the location of the CSS file, knowing full well those URLs are relative to it's original location, without updating those relative URLs... is a bug.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355935/mvc4-stylebundle-not-resolving-images

Answer (score 0):

I would normally cater for this server side.

For example (using ASP.NET C#) would commonly append a `baseUrl` to the image and define the URL in the `web.config`.

I would then use debug or release versions of the `web.config` to transform the baseUrl appropriately.

As a result, my HTML files would either have parts, or the entirety of the URLs constructed server side (or at least have the `baseUrl` appended server side) or potentially have the `baseUrl` projected into client side code perhaps via Session or JavaScript.

**EDIT:** To clarify, I don't mean setting something like http://mysite.com as a baseUrl, I would advocate something like `../../../image/` as my development baseUrl, and translate this to `/image/` when in production, or something similar

Comment: A base URL is useless for a CSS file.  The url in the CSS file is static, so it cannot be modified (especially if it's a 3rd party plugin).  If the paths in CSS files are relative to the CSS file's location, and minification changes the CSS file's location without updating those relative paths, then that's a bug/oversight in the minification process.