# why my div backgrond image not works in bundlying?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

i developed a simple web application by mvc4 on .net4.5 to test bundling i thins this is a greate feature and i like it.

i created a div with background image for it.in theme folder create my style sheet file and add it to my view when i run my sample

div show it's background image and works nice but when i change bundling mode to release mode by adding this syntax

(  BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;  ) in global scape file and run it again background image can not be shown .

i test it in this mode and change image path to     background-image: url('themes/500.jpg'); and it works but as i know it should work without themes in part of images pas and if image pas is wrong how it works in debug mode?

i want to know is it a bug or i did some things wrong?

```
<div class="mystyle">blablabla</div>

.mystyle {
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: 0px 0px;
   width: 300px;
   height: 400px;
   background-image: url('500.jpg');
 }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't a div background image work with minified CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17171190/why-doesnt-a-div-background-image-work-with-minified-css)

Comment: Show how you create bundle and how you set to view