# MVC4 Bundling misdirect background-image url

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification

I have this bundling configuration:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/styles/style1").Include("~/Content/library/styles/style1.css")
```

Then I added this code to render the bundled CSS:

```
@Styles.Render("~/styles/style1")
```

My CSS has this content:

```
.style1 {
  background-image: url("../img/image.png");
}
```

Due to bundling, the  path of background image is misdirected to ~/Content/library/img/image.png instead of ~/img/image.png. I don't want to edit the CSS file path because many other pages are using it. Do you know of any solution to it or am I missing a configuration in bundling?

Comment: ~/Content/styles/style1 style1 is your css file? then you should use it so ~/Content/styles/style1.css

Comment: @xurca edited my question now, but i hope you got my question, the main concept is that bundling is misdirecting url paths

Comment: well i can suggest you to check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355935/mvc4-stylebundle-not-resolving-images

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're gonna need to apply the `CssRewriteUrlTransform` to fix this:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/styles/style1")
                .Include("~/Content/styles/style1", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())
```

Alternatively, you can also use absolute paths in your stylesheets.

**P.S:** As stated in the comments, you have to add the **[Web Optimization Package](http://aspnetoptimization.codeplex.com/)** to your project through Codeplex or NuGet to be able to use the CssRewriteUrlTransform class

Comment: is CssRewriteUrlTransform class builtin in VS2012?

Comment: Try to add a reference to `System.Web.Optimization`. if you can't find it, look here: http://aspnetoptimization.codeplex.com

Comment: Or, alternatively, use NuGet: `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization`

Comment: Beware of issues with CssRewriteUrlTransform, like data url's and virtual directories, and consider using [CssRewriteUrlTransformFixed.cs](https://github.com/benmccallum/AspNetBundling/blob/master/AspNetBundling/CssRewriteUrlTransformFixed.cs), instead.