# Hell in CSS's that reference images after ASP.NET MVC4 deployment

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a MVC4 application that has a Content folder, and inside I have several CSS folders, belonging to different jquery plugins. Each folder has its own set of images.

After deployment the application, the CSS get minified and called from /Content folder. All images that reference the CSS files are of course, broken, because system did not modified images path accordingly.

How can I solve it without the need of manually changing all CSS files to use absolute paths for images?

I have read a lot of answers here but none the those worked.

EDIT:

The original CSS file is at /Content/jquery/select2/select2.css

That CSS reference images in /Content/jquery/select2/ folder.

When deploying, the bundled minified CSS is at /Content, and since images are still relative referenced, they are not found.

Thanks
Jaime

Comment: What are the 'final' urls in your plugin css? Your actual folder structure? Are you relying on the default bundling of an MVC4 project? Details, friend...details.

Comment: I have added more details.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MVC4 StyleBundle not resolving images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355935/mvc4-stylebundle-not-resolving-images)

Comment: no... I have read that page with no help..... however, never mind now... I have moved the images to an absolute path and changed the CSS manually..... I think Microsoft should consider this and deliver a solution