# Relative path transformations in CSS bundles

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to bundle the CSS files for my MVC5 project and I'm running into a problem with relative URLs. Before you mash the duplicate question button, I've read other similar questions and the answers haven't dealt with the particular situation I need to handle.

The project I'm working on will be run as an application under a regular IIS site, meaning it won't sit at the root of the domain.  This is a problem when using the out-of-the-box URL transform `CssRewriteUrlTransform()` as it (stupidly, in my humble opinion) doesn't take into account the application name in the URL, instead it generates absolute paths treating the domain root as the starting level.  Say I have the following folder structure:

```
site
'--- content
     |--- css
     |    '--- style.css
     '--- images
          '--- logo.png
```

If I use a relative URL like this:

```
background-image: url('../images/logo.png');
```

It gets transformed to:

```
background-image: url('http://domainname.com/content/images/logo.png');
```

The problem is, I need it to respect the application/subdirectory name when it does the transform. The solution should also preserve query strings.

```
background-image: url('http://domainname.com/applicationname/content/images/logo.png[?querystring]
```

The closest I've found is the solution offered by AcidPAT on this question: [MVC4 StyleBundle not resolving images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355935/mvc4-stylebundle-not-resolving-images)

But that solution doesn't compile for me, as it seems to treat `response.Files` as an IEnumerable when in fact it's an IEnumerable - maybe this changed from MVC4 to MVC5.

**Summary**

I need a means of automatically transforming relative paths in my CSS into absolute paths when bundling them. The solution needs to understand the *actual* location of the application, so it should work if the application is installed under a subdirectory of the domain. The solution also needs to preserve any query strings from the relative URL.

Can anyone provide some guidance on this?

The closest solution is this gist: https://gist.github.com/dotnetchris/3d1e4fe9b0fa77eefc82 with the only problem being that it seems to be incompatible with MVC5. Specifically the block starting at line 12 which begins to iterate through the list of `BundleFile` objects seems to be treating them as `FileInfo` objects and therefore calls to non-existent properties are being made.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[I believe this could be a bug with CssRewriteUrlTransform](http://aspnetoptimization.codeplex.com/workitem/83). It will resolve the host but not the virtual directory. This is what I use instead. It's just a wrapper class that allows the bundling process to resolve correctly.

```
public class CssRewriteUrlTransformWrapper : IItemTransform
{
    public string Process(string includedVirtualPath, string input)
    {
        return new CssRewriteUrlTransform().Process("~" + VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(includedVirtualPath), input);
    }
}
```

Usage...

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css")
       .Include("~/Content/Site.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransformWrapper()));
```

Comment: Remember that the url in the css must be wrapped into quotes