# Debug Local vs Production with CSS path not working on Local Debug

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this MVC website that I'm a part of.

I noticed that the arrow images were not showing up were running **LOCALLY** of which I heard that it worked fine on **production**  Then to me it was most likely a path issue with **localhost:port#/**   vs.  **ProductionWebsitename**/

I changed **css** from :

(works on production)

```
.k-icon {
    background-image: url("../Content/Bootstrap/sprite.png") !important;
}
```

TO

(works local debug)

```
.k-icon {
    background-image: url("../Bootstrap/sprite.png") !important;
}
```

1. Am I not doing this correctly?
2. What are my options for relative paths to work ?
3. This is an asp.net MVC 5 website , with CSS file ,  is there a slick way of handling both?

Comment: What is the full path filename of your css file? It could be that you use bundling for production, but not when debugging.

Comment: The problem is bundling on non-debug builds is changing relative paths in CSS.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355935/mvc4-stylebundle-not-resolving-images

Comment: @JackB     C:\dev\Envy\Envy.Presentation.Web\Content\app\common.css