# Background for body CSS not working after publishing webapp in IIS

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-4

```aspx
<body class="login-body">
    <div id="body">
        @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
        <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
            @RenderBody()
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
```

And CSS style is

```css
.login-body {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("../Images/bg2.jpg") no-repeat fixed center center / cover ;
}
```

It works fine locally but once published on IIS7 I found this error in console.

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).    http://sdw2629/Images/bg2.jpg 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Failed to load which resource?

Comment: Is your webserver allowed to reach the ressource ?

Comment: @William yes its allowed to reach the resource,i have a Images folder placed in the webserver folder.

Comment: @SagarJagadesh What happens when you try to click on this link? http://sdw2629/Images/bg2.jpg

Comment: @PraveenKumar This css     background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("MustardWebPortal/Images/bg2.jpg") no-repeat fixed center center / cover; works fine, Here MustardWebPortal is my root folder..

Answer (score 0):

Solved the Issue following this post by moving the css and image to the same rootfolder.

[MVC4 StyleBundle not resolving images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355935/mvc4-stylebundle-not-resolving-images?lq=1)