# How to render image path correctly in Razor when using bundle configuration

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, razor, optimization

**BundleConfig.cs snippet**

```
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/css").Include(
                    "~/content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
                    "~/content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css"
    }
```

**_Layout.cshtml snippet**

```
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/css")
```

**jquery.ui.theme.css snippet**

```
    url(images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png)
```

Firebug reports that the image (my_app_path) **/ bundles / images /** ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png` 404 not found.

How can I tell Razor that the correct path is actually (my_app_path) **/ content / themes / base / images /** ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png`?

**EDIT:** ELMAH spits this error for the same issue:

> System.Web.HttpException: The controller for path ' **/ bundles /
>   images /** ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png' was not found or does not
>   implement IController.

Answer (score -1):

This is happening because your CSS files aren't being rewritten to transform their relative paths.  You can make this happen by changing to the following:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/css").Include(
                "~/content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
                "~/content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css",
                new CssRewriteUrlTransform()));
```

Comment: I'm sure this will work but for some reason it seems like a workaround. I may be wrong but was hoping to get a solution without having to edit the css file or move files around.

Comment: Indeed.  Found a better solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11386982/163495) and updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: in [that link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11386982/163495) there is also a comment by avidenic that this may only work for websites in IIS and not applications under the website. mine is an application. nevertheless i tried. couple of things - needed to update system.web.optimization from 1.0.0 to latest version to resolve CssRewriteUrlTransform. and now i get `cannot convert type CssRewriteUrlTransform to string` build error. i just ended up taking a totally different route - added two bundles instead of one - separating them based on folder locations.

Comment: There is no such overloaded method of the `.Include()` one.
I have tried to split them to different `.Include()` calls but it it doesn't work.
This doesn't work until you change the bundle virtual path to `"~/Content/themes/base/css"` instead of the `"~/bundles/css"`