# Why is Windows Azure adding '/bundles/' into all of my css image file paths?

Tags: css, azure, background-image, filepath

I am using the css property:

```
background-image: url(/Content/Images/background.jpg);
```

However when deployed to Windows Azure, it comes up with the file not found error because it is trying to retrieve the image from:

```
...azurewebsites.net/bundles/Content/Images/background.jpg
```

I have tried:

```
'~/', '../', 'Content/', '/Content' & even the full path.
```

when I simply go to the url of the image in the web browser, it loads the image so I know it is there.

What is the best way to remove or account for this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Please check if you have bundling enabled in your application. The file you want to check is `BundleConfig.cs` in `App_Start` folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is Windows Azure adding '/bundles/' into all of my css image file paths?

Your CSS file is getting [bundled](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification). ASP.NET is putting your CSS file into a new file and storing it at `mydomain.net/bundles/somefile.css`. The web browser is looking for your image *relative to the CSS files location*.

This is only happening on Azure because bundling only runs in release configuration not in debug configuration. So, you can test bundling locally by setting `<compilation debug="false" />` in your web.config file.

> What is the best way to remove ... this problem?

Take a look at this: [MVC4 StyleBundle not resolving images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355935/mvc4-stylebundle-not-resolving-images) and this [MVC cannot display image using background-url in css - uses bundling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12351418/mvc-cannot-display-image-using-background-url-in-css-uses-bundling), or just do not use bundling. :)