# how center vertical bootstrap button?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, vertical-alignment

I want center vertical bootstrap button on an image , I do it like this :

```
http://jsfiddle.net/fhd031hf/
```

I use `margin-top:-200px` , is that true or there are another better way ?

Comment: Please see my answer below. Using the method i have provided it will be responsive and it will not mess up the design when going to a smaller resolution.

Comment: Thank you dear , I don't know how I handle it when images loaded from database :/ @Matthew

Answer (score 1):

Your approach as you see will work but instead you could/should use position relative and absolute stylings. They are more intuitive when somebody else or yourself has to look at the code some time later again.

To achieve your desired results you have to add *position: relative* to the containing div and *position: absolute; top: 200px*; to the button.

```
<div style="position: relative">
  <img style="width:100% ; height:400px;" class="center-block img-responsive" src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/daisy_pollen_flower_220533.jpg" />
  <button style="position: absolute; top: 200px" type="button" class="btn btn-default ">TitleText</button>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fhd031hf/2/

**Edit:**
Seeing that you are using a responsive class for the image please take in consideration that both appproaches will break the design when the screen solution is smaller than the original image.

Comment: thank you dear , yes as you said , it works fine now but when I shrink the browser it  shows a little bad . thank you again :) @Felix

Answer (score 1):

a couple of things I noticed about your fiddle:

1.) you were not resourcing bootstrap correctly. you had the .css file resourced but you were missing the .js file.

2.) your div structure in no way indicated that you were using bootstrap. Bootstrap has classes that you must attribute to your divs in order for bootstrap to work properly. Here is a getting started link for using bootstrap. [Bootstrap Getting Started](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/).

Check out this fiddle I have made for you. Instead of using an html img tag I am using a div with a background-image. Setting that div to a relative position and the button inside that div to an absolute position, it allows the button to stay exactly in the center of the image no matter what the screen resolution.

The only downside to this is you need to specify a height for the button. Other than that I uses this method all the time and it hasn't given me any issues.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fhd031hf/3/)

```
    .center-block.img-responsive {
        background: url('http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/daisy_pollen_flower_220533.jpg') no-repeat center center scroll;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        position: relative;
        height: 500px;
    }
    .btn.btn-default {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100px;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        height: 40px;
        margin: auto;
    }
```

Comment: thank you , yes I'm new in bootstrap . thank you for your code but My image loaded from database , and I have  a lot of  images @Matthew

Comment: so you don't have control of how the image is loaded on the page?

Comment: No , I control it with `src="@Url.Content(item.GoodImage.ToString())"` and it works correctly , but I don't know how change it to background image in div

Comment: Is that javascript you are using to set the src?

Comment: I came across another question of yours which told me that you are using ASP MVC5. I did some research into that and it may be complicated or not useful to you i found this other post showing how to use `@Url.Content()` directly in css. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12351418/mvc-cannot-display-image-using-background-url-in-css-uses-bundling).

edit: sorry i could not be more help. I wish you good luck in your project.

Comment: No , I used asp.net  mvc5  with razor engine and it is Razor syntax

Comment: Thank you very much dear :) , you helped me a lot . a little of my problem solved .